# SQL selecting row in table that matches n number of rows in another table

Tags: sql, db2

I'm fairly new using SQL and perhaps there is a better way to phrase this problem, but can be clearly be described using the following example...

In a video game database, I have a player table with multiple accounts:

```
create table Player (
    login   varchar(15) not null,
    name    varchar(15) not null,
    gender  char(1)     not null,
    ...
    );
```

Each account has multiple avatars

```
create table Avatar (
    login   varchar(15) not null,
    name    varchar(15) not null,
    gender  char(1)
    ...
    );
```

I am trying to query Player where ALL of their avatars match their gender. Hence, only if a player is male, and all of their avatars are also male, I want to include the row (and vice versa with female).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Player p WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Avatar a WHERE a.login = p.login AND a.gender <> p.gender)
```

This should do the trick. Although it also matches Players where there is no Avatar at all.

```
SELECT * FROM Player p WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Avatar a WHERE a.login = p.login AND a.gender <> p.gender) AND COUNT(SELECT * FROM Avatar a WHERE a.login = p.login) >= 1
```

... of course assuming that 'login' is the unique identifier for a user.

Comment: The first query seems to work (properly narrowing down), but the second one gives an unexpected token :/

Answer (score 1):

Use `Group By` and `Having` clause. Filter the names with distinct count of  `gender` is 1 in `Having` clause.

```
select name 
from Avatar 
Group by name 
Having count(distinct gender) = 1
```

or

```
Having Min(gender) = Max(gender)
```